# Get Day of the Week Ahead

Tags: android, android-calendar

Let's say today is any random day and I'm trying to find the date for next Tuesday. Currently I'm only able to find the date for the Tuesday of this week...

```
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.TUESDAY);
```

How can I get NEXT Tuesday and forget about last Tuesday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

```
cal.set( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.TUESDAY );
cal.add( Calendar.DATE, 7 );
```

Usually, these sorts of questions result in a bunch of people rightfully yelling "[JODA](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)!"

---

[edited by bwoogie] My final code:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.TUESDAY);


        if(c.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
        }
```

Comment: ok this sounds good. but I will need to check if Tuesday hasnt passed though, right? Otherwise it will skip to next week if today is Monday. Hmmm?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.TUESDAY);
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 7);

SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/d/yyyy");

Log.d("Next", f.format(cal.getTime()));
```